What should the protocol be for handling requests to refund bounties if the question is closed?
This is inspired by this global meta post that came up today. In it, an author was genuinely unaware that the question they asked was off-topic and it got closed while they had a bounty on it, and they asked the question after seeing an outdated answer that questions with active bounties cannot be closed.
Historically, if a question with an active bounty was later deemed off-topic or otherwise closeable for any reason, this would involve a moderator having to clear out the bounty, refunding it to the starter. However, after this year's feature change to allow questions with active bounties to be closed, the reputation isn't refunded to the bounty starter any longer. This can create issues where bounty starters feel that they've wasted their reputation, especially in cases where a question was just barely outside the site's scope or if the question was closed incorrectly and even though it's later reopened the time it could have received an answer is reduced.
An experienced Stack Exchange user and moderator on other sites answered that they would have refunded the bounty for the specific case brought up there (of a question that was barely outside SO's scope). They also state that the ideal case is for the bounty to be cleared out automatically if the question is closed provided that the author wasn't involved in the closure, but I can see some issues with that - specifically in the case of "tactical" bounties where the bounty starter uses it to feature a question they know is a bad fit in the hope it gets answered before it's closed (these bounties also used to prevent closure, but that's no longer the case, though close reviews are still prevented).
As such, given the current functionality, my question is what should the protocol be in case a user requests their bounty be refunded if the question is closed?

Should whether the question is blatantly a bad fit or subtly so factor into this equation?
Should pending close votes cast before the bounty is placed factor into this equation?
Or should all such requests be rejected out of hand, because it's up to the bounty starter to know whether or not the question is a good fit?


I personally believe that bounties shouldn’t be able to be refunded for any reason, even if the question, is closed for being out of scope. If you don’t know the rules well enough and offer a bounty on a question that’s out of scope, that isn’t something we should prevent. You only make that mistake once. In fact I believe once a question is closed, even if the bounty is awarded, an answer it was awarded should lose the bounty. Users should unable to benefit from a bounty if a question is closed

@SecurityHound What if the question is closed incorrectly and is subsequently reopened?

How often does that happen? Specifically, closing a question with a bounty, which is then ultimately reopened? I would want the bounty to be taken away from an answer only during the period of the bounty (7 days), once the bounty ended, it would be permanent. Just looking to encourage users to not answer a question that’s is obviously out of scope, currently you have nothing to lose, and many users will answer a question with a bounty despite obvious problems with the question.

Why was this downvoted? These are reasonable concerns. And there is no 'downvotes = disagreement' as this is not a [meta-tag:feature-request].

No refunds. Bounties awarded for closed questions should be unrewarded when the question is closed. I don't really care what happens if a question is reopened, whatever is easiest. As you might have guessed, I'm not a fan of bounties (although I've used them) and wouldn't mind if they were eliminated altogether.

@CPlus - The question proposes a question “should … happen”, i disagree with that notion, so I downvoted the question. I am like other’s bounties are absolutely abused way to often by users who should know better

@SecurityHound I do not really agree with that notion of voting. Since the meaning of the question could easily be reversed by 'should ... not happen' In my opinion, if '...' should not happen, you can post or look for answers that say so and upvote them. The question could be perfectly still valid.

@CPlus - You asked why this question was being downvoted, so I explained my vote, it’s unnecessary to claim my reasoning is flawed.

@SecurityHound Note that the part of the question you quoted as your reason has since been edited out.

Ok? @gparyani What am I supposed to do with that information? Doesn’t change my feedback about what I quoted.

Any way you cut it, we are not going to guarantee that a bounty on a closed question is going to be refunded, because we cannot guarantee that. It's a fundamental logistical issue, regardless of what the discussion here might resolve to. Refunding a bounty requires that a moderator act prior to the expiration and/or awarding of the bounty. Moderators can't refund the bounty after that happens. Even when the flag queue was low (it's significantly improved, but not low), moderators did not, necessarily, get to a flag about a bounty prior to when it was impossible to refund.

I do not see much of a problem for refunding bounties on closed questions without answers. A "better luck next time" seems like no harm no foul.
The refunds could be limited in some way, for example, the bounty will not be refunded after N days. However, finding a good value for N is left as an implementation detail. If adopted at all.
What is the biggest harm one can do with bounties that end up with questions closed? They bounty a question, it gets closed, bounty another, it also gets closed, repeat forever because they will never run out of rep? That seems like an effort at cleaning up the site more than harm.
If the bounties really gets high, for any reason, that should be an exception. We have exception handlers. However, it seems there is a low chance for that. Eventually, a chain bounty behaviour is going to attract an answer before closure. Which means the bounty becomes non-refundable.

In your first paragraph, you mean automatically refunding bounties?

Automatically, or you "ask" for it somehow (fill out a form, or a modflag), or whatever. I don't really care and I don't think the precise mechanism matters. Nor is it my intention to provide such mechanism. I believe my answer is applicable to all ways you can get a bounty refunded.

With the current implementation, only moderators can refund bounties, so I'd assume they're going to check if it's being abused beforehand.

I was pinged about answering this, and here goes. I think the 'fundamental' problem is that 'one' problem, essentially tactical bounties, is tackled, but there's knock on effects that don't seem to have been addressed.
I'd also note that since at least two days need to pass after a question is asked - it would mean OP asked the question in presumed good faith, the community didn't close it in that period and someone decided that its useful enough to bounty.
If the question had been close voted in that period and the question was bountied, I'd say tactical bountying is possible and I'd be disinclined to think refunding a bounty is a good idea here. I also certainly don't think a bounty refund should happen due to user initiated circumstances - vandalism or having the user  close their own posts for whatever reason.
However within reason, I think a closed question should get the bounty refunded. The point of a bounty is to get attention to a question - every existing bounty reason except "to reward an existing answer" seems to be "I'm using my reputation to advertise this post".
To me, it feels like the 'correct' solution would be to have an automatic refund of a bounty under specific conditions. A full feature request for this is beyond the scope of this post, but would follow the rough conditions stated above.

I am in support of refunding bounties on closed questions. VLAZ appropriately points out that existing community actions and moderation tools can prevent abuse of such a feature.
I have seen some people voicing the opinion that a user should lose his reputation for posting (or even answering) a question that gets closed. The presumption here that the OP of a closed question is (always) guilty of complacency/indifference to SO rules. However, there are still times when a good question is loosely skimmed over and closed without appropriate comprehension, or when a longstanding community member puts forth the right amount of effort and consideration in composing a question but still misses something which warrants a close. Sometimes, you really just need a second set of eyes.
And while it is true that "some men just want to watch the world burn", these users are an edge case and we have moderators to handle those. In the end, we should be asking ourselves, is it really necessary to punish community members for honest mistakes?
